# Controller not working when ngMock is included

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-mock

My code without ngMock is ['here'](http://plnkr.co/edit/AB9rYzyHDSgFz3mYm9og?p=preview).

```
var app = angular.module('logExample',[]);
app.controller('LogController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
$scope.$log = $log;
$scope.message = 'Hello World!';
}]);
```

When I add 'ngMock' in the angular module in requirements, the controller doesn't executes, check ['here'](http://plnkr.co/edit/SJDhsm1CziwiWYgd1Hrd?p=preview).

```
var app = angular.module('logExample',['ngMock']);
app.controller('LogController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
$scope.$log = $log;
$scope.message = 'Hello World!';
}]);
```

Can someone tell me what is the issue? I am trying to use angular mock for logging. I wish to get logs according to the levels, ie, I want some way to get error logs, warning logs etc separately.

Thanks.

Comment: but is it right to use it in non-test code ?

Comment: Din't get what ur saying. I'm trying to ask that, when 'ngMock' is included in the module, why does the controller not get executed?

Comment: yes I understood your question, but it interesting for me why you are trying  to use it in you production code ? where you are going to use it ? if for not tests

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to include the module? I think you can just reference the js for your tests using a test runner.

Comment: I was trying this--> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock

Comment: Yeah I read that. I know it says there to load the module, but do you really need to? My understanding is you can still mock these things without loading the module

Comment: In this case I can, but since my app is too big, I couldn't create a fiddle of it. This is just a temp to display the issue due to mock.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are using `ngMock` module in the dependency list. To run apps with a mocked backend, you should include `ngMockE2E`.

ngMock is only used in unit tests, where you won't run the entire application, only a part of it.

See the app running here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/l6PadUOdoip4obWXLflO?p=preview